# How to efficiently generate a symbolic function/model with prescribed calibration routine?

Tags: functions, function-construction

Imagine you have a model `m[A]` depending on some matrix variable `A`, for simplicity $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$. The model is a complex algebraic expression of `A` such that some intermediate computations might be done in, e.g., a `Module`. Further, assume that the model `m[A]` has some internal paramters, say `p1,p2,p3` that you do **not** want to specify. A calibration routine for given model `Calibrate[m]` is expected to return an **efficient callable model**, after solving some internal conditions, that the given model has to fulfill. How would you do this, e.g., for the following case? I am able to do it, but I am unsure, if using `MapThread` and a pure function in the last line of my `Calibrate` is a good idea in terms of fast evaluations of the calibrated model. Do you know better options?

Model

```
m[A_] := Module[
   {temp},
   temp = Transpose[A].A - IdentityMatrix@Length@A;
   temp = Flatten[p1*A + p2*temp.temp + p3*A.A];
   temp.temp + 10
   ];
```

Symbolic and explicit evaluation

```
A = Array[a, {3, 3}];
m@A // Variables // Sort
Id = IdentityMatrix@3;
m@Id
```

> {p1, p2, p3, a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[2, 3], a[3, 1], a[3, 2], a[3, 3]}
>
> 10 + 3 (p1 + p3)^2

Calibration routine

```
Calibrate[m_] := Module[
   {A, a, der, cond, mout},
   A = Array[a, {3, 3}];
   der = D[m[A], {A, 1}] /. MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@A, Flatten@Id}];
   cond = First@Solve[der == 0];
   Print["Information:", cond];
   mout = Simplify[m[A] /. cond];
   (*How to improve the generation of the output function (following line)?*)
   mout /. MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@A, Flatten@#}] &
   ];
```

Calibrate `m` and check

```
m2 = Calibrate[m];
(*Check symbolic evaluation*)
m2@A // Variables // Sort
(*Check explicit evaluation*)
m2@Id
(*Check condition*)
D[m2[A], {A, 1}] /. MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@A, Flatten@Id}]
```

> Information:{p3->-p1}
>
> {p1, p2, a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[2, 3], a[3, 1], a[3, 2], a[3, 3]}
>
> 10
>
> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
Calibrate[m_] := Module[{A, der, cond},
   A = Array[Indexed[\[FormalA], {##}] &, {3, 3}];
   der = D[m[A], {A, 1}] /. MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@A, Flatten@Id}];
   cond = First@Solve[der == 0];
   Print["Information:", cond];
   Function @@ {\[FormalA], Simplify[m[A] /. cond]}
   ];
```

The point is to `Apply` `Function` to a list of its argument and return value. This way the return value is correctly evaluated. Using the formal symbol `\[FormalA]` that cannot be overwritten avoids a lot of hassle with temporary variants of the symbol `a` induced by `Module`. Finally, `Indexed` allows indexing like `Part`, but does not trow errors when used symbolically. Moreover, it prints as nicely as `Subscript` (which should be avoided as we all know).

If you are interested: It is also possible to generate a `CompiledFunction` in a similar way. The only thing one has to know is the names of all the parameters that are involved in the model (because the parameters have to be included into the argument pattern of the `CompiledFunction`).

So for this specific example, one can do this:

```
cCalibrate[m_] := Block[{A, a, der, cond},
   A = Array[Compile`GetElement[a, ##] &, {3, 3}];
   der = D[m[A], {A, 1}] /. MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, {Flatten@A, Flatten@Id}];
   cond = First@Solve[der == 0];
   Print["Information:", cond];
   With[{code = Simplify[m[A] /. cond]},
    Compile[{{a, _Real, 2}, {p1, _Real}, {p2, _Real}, {p3, _Real}},
     code,
     CompilationTarget -> "C",
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True,
     RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

I use `Block` instead of `Module` here. Tends to work better than `Module` when preparing expressions for `Compile`.

And now:

```
cm2 = cCalibrate[m];

n = 1000000;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 3, 3}];
cm2[A, 1, 2, 3]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.039036

I hope this answers also the efficiency part of your question.

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much. That answers a lot a questions on my side :D

Comment: You're welcome. I am happy to help!